# Getting geohash of LINESTRING in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, shapely, geopandas, linestring, geohash

I have some `LINESTRING` in PostGIS.

```
 LINESTRING(104.011 30.637,104.014 30.638,104.022 30.640,104.026 30.645)
 LINESTRING(104.022 30.666,104.031 30.659)
 LINESTRING(104.044 30.655,104.056 30.655)
```

I want to get all the geohash that intersects `LINESTRING` on level 6 (or others). So I excepted result like:

```
[wm3yqc,wm3yr1,wm3yr4]
[wm3yrn,wm3yrj,wm3yrm]
[wm3yrs,wm3yru]
```

I know `ST_GeoHash` to get geohash in PostGIS. But as the document says:

> For non-points, the starting point of the calculation is the center of
>   the bounding box of the geometry.

**Add**

There is a bug to compute a geohash for vertices in adding vertices by `ST_Segmentize` method. As shown in the figure below, if parameter `max_segment_length` of `ST_Segmentize` is larger than  the length of `LINESTRING` passing through the grid geohash, it will be omitted.
[image]

The length of the length of `LINESTRING` passing through the grid geohash may be  close to zero. We can't avoid this result by adjusting the parameters.

Does anyone have a good solution? It is also acceptable to use `geopandas` or `shapely` without complex loop.

Comment: georaptor? https://github.com/ashwin711/georaptor (geohash polygons)

Comment: @Mapperz The input required for `georaptor` is a set of geohash, which is exactly what I want to get result. It can't meet my needs.

Comment: 1) Determine your area of interest 2) Create polygons of all geohashes needed to cover that AOI with https://blog.tafkas.net/2018/09/28/creating-a-grid-based-on-geohashes/ 3) Store the geohash polygon layer into PostGIS 4) Select polygons intersected by lines with ST_Intersects.

Comment: @user30184 Maybe this is the final solution. Thank you again.

Comment: It might be possible to do everything in PostGIS. 1) Create a point grid with suitable spacing 2) Compute geohashes for them 3) Create polygons for geohashes with https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoHash.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract the vertices from your linestrings and let PostGIS to compute a geohash for each.

```
select ST_GeoHash((g.gdump).geom) as geohash
from
(select ST_DumpPoints(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(104.011 30.637,104.014 30.638,104.022 30.640,104.026 30.645)')) as gdump) as g;

Result:
"wm3yqc63rywzdjsm3vp9"
"wm3yqckxmc5ubvje34ve"
"wm3yr1fdbmcp27grpn80"
"wm3yr4v2j6p9s14kvgtk"
```

You can control the number of vertices in geometries at least with ST_Segmentize (add points) and ST_SnapToGrid (combine close points).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This essence is to calculate `LINESTRING`'s geohash by vertices , but because the limitation of `max_segment_length `'s , doing so will lead to missing. You can see what I added to the question.